# Avoid printing file name when using 'FIND' command in batch script

Tags: batch-file

When I use find command to search for a string and print the string, the file name is also printed. Is there a way to avoid printing the file name.

For Ex:
Consider a file Sample.log which contains,

```
INF000005: <0> Error(s) and <0> Warning(s) detected.   
INF000006: Execution completed successfully.
```

I run a batch file with following command.

```
find " error " Sample.log >Result.txt
```

The current output in Result.txt is

```
---------- .\Sample.log  
INF000005: <0> Error(s) and <0> Warning(s) detected.
```

Expected output in Result.txt is

```
INF000005: <0> Error(s) and <0> Warning(s) detected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples:

```
find " error " <Sample.log >Result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way is to pipe it into `more`:

```
find " error " Sample.log|more +2 >Result.txt
```

"+2" because find still prints out one empty line before the header.

If you expect to find more than 65534 errors, more will interrupt the script and prompt input to continue.

However, the answer Klitos Kyriacou provided is more reliable and possibly even simpler.

Comment: `more` might hang (await user input) when it receives more that 65534 lines of text; perhaps you should mention this restriction in your answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
type Sample.log | find " error "  >Result.txt
```

will avoid the problem. `find` shows you the filename because it's possible to `find` a string in an afn like `*.txt`